# expected initializer before â token

Tags: c++, vector

When I try to build a forloop for vector like this:

```
  vector<int> v;

  int  a;
    while (cin>>a){
      if(i<=0 || i>=10)
        cout << "Please enter int between 0 and 10:" << endl;
      else
        v.push_back(a);
    }

  int min;
  int sum;
  for (int &i: v){
    if(v.empty())
      min = i;
    else(i<min){
     min = i;
    sum += i;
    }
  }
```

It shows :expected initializer before â token

Where did i get wrong? Thanks so much!

.bashrc:

Here is my .bashrc:

```
  # .bashrc

    # User specific aliases and functions
    export PATH=/usr/remote/gcc-4.8/bin:$PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/remote/gcc-4.8/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    alias g++='g++ -std=c++11'


    # Source global definitions
    if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
    fio9
```

Comment: Does the error message really say `â token` (small letter 'a' with circumflex)? I see no such token in your code.

Comment: Presumably `if(i<=0 || i>=10)` should be `if(a<=0 || a>=10)`. Either you have a variable `i` that you didn't show us, or you got another error message from your compiler that you didn't show us. Next time, *please* (1) show us a [short self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) (follow that link and read it), and (2) show us the exact copy-and-pasted error message, clearly indicating (preferably by a comment in the source code) which line it refers to. And you never answered my question: did the error message really refer to `â token`? If you want us to help you, you need to help us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to initialize min before using it for the else if condition.

However, you simply have an else with a condition which is a syntax error.

This works for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;

    int  i;
    while (cin >> i) {
        if(i < 0 || i > 10)
            cout << "Please enter int between 0 and 10:" << endl;
        else
            v.push_back(i);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int min = INT_MAX;

    for (int &i: v) {
        if (i < min)
            min = i;
        sum += i;
    }

    cout << "min: " << min << endl;
    cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

I build this code with the following command: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`

Output is:

```
1
2
3
min: 1
sum: 6
```